# How to test for the increasing and decreasing trend in a non-time series data

Tags: r, forecasting, trend

I have the following data frame:

```
dat <- structure(list(peptide_name = c("P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2", "P4", "P4", "P4", "P4", "P4", "P4", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3"), dose = c("0mM", 
"0.3mM", "1mM", "3mM", "10mM", "20mM", "0mM", "0.3mM", "1mM", 
"3mM", "10mM", "20mM", "0mM", "0.3mM", "1mM", "3mM", "10mM", 
"20mM", "0mM", "0.3mM", "1mM", "3mM", "10mM", "20mM"), prolif_score = c(1, 
1.174927114, 1.279883382, 1.752186589, 1.994169096, 2.358600583, 
1, 1.046454768, 1.339853301, 1.293398533, 1.026894866, 1.17264410515205, 
1, 0.928020566, 0.920308483, 1.071979434, 1.195372751, 1.524421594, 
1, 1.293233083, 1.483709273, 1.468671679, 1.192982456, 0.463659148
)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

What I want to have is an indicator that can differentiate between upward (P2, P1)
and non-upward (P4 and P3) trend. As you can see the R value of [linear model](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lm) used for that is not useful.
For example R score in P3 is positive just like P2 and P1.

How can I do that in R?

This is the code I have to create that plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(ggpubr)

lm_rsq_dat <- dat %>% 
    mutate(dose = as.numeric(gsub("mM", "", dose))) %>% 
    group_by(peptide_name) %>% 
    do(model = glance(lm(dose ~ prolif_score, data = .))) %>% 
    unnest(model) %>% 
    arrange(desc(adj.r.squared)) %>%
    dplyr::select(peptide_name, adj.r.squared) %>% 
    print(n = 100)  
      
# Plot --------------------------------------------------------------------
plot_dat <- dat %>% 
  left_join(lm_rsq_dat, by = "peptide_name") %>%
  mutate(r.squared = formatC(adj.r.squared, format = "e", 
   digits = 2)) %>% 
  mutate(npeptide_name = paste0( peptide_name, " (R=", 
     r.squared, ")")) #%>% 

nspn <- plot_dat %>% 
  dplyr::select(peptide_name, npeptide_name, adj.r.squared) 
     %>% 
  arrange(match(peptide_name, rsq_dat$peptide_name)) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  pull(npeptide_name)
    
plot_dat <- plot_dat %>% 
  mutate(npeptide_name = factor(npeptide_name, 
           levels =   nspn))
    
end_dat <- plot_dat %>% 
  filter(dose == "20mM")

  ggline(plot_dat,
         y = "prolif_score", x = "dose",
         color = "npeptide_name", 
         size = 1, 
         facet.by = "npeptide_name", scales = "free_y",
         palette = get_palette("npg",  
                  length( dat$peptide_name))
  ) +
  xlab("Dose") +
  ylab("Prolif. Score") +
  grids(linetype = "dashed")  +
  rremove("legend") + 
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 0.5, 
        vjust = 0.5, size = 12))
```

Comment: My advise is to check the statistical significance of the covariates in the model.  Suppose the linear model is defined as a function of a single covariate.  If $\mu_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i$, then given $\widehat{\beta}_1$ is positive and statistically significant, then you have an increasing trend.  Likewise if it is negative and statistically significant, then you have a decreasing trend.  If you fit the model $\mu_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \beta_2 x_i^2$, then you should check if $\widehat{\beta}_2$ is positive (increasing parabola) or negative (decreasing parabola)

Comment: The correlation coefficient $R$ *is* a valid indicator of trend according to the procedure you are using.  This means you have a different conception of "trend" and how to measure it, likely requiring a completely different procedure.  There are many potential alternatives.  Could you therefore please explain more precisely what you mean by "trend"?  We could then tailor our answers to your needs rather than having to guess what you're trying to get at.